# Rails order by in active record for search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to organize search result in rails.
If i search for a string eg "food products" using

```
Products.where("name ILIKE '%food%' or name ILIKE '%products%' or name ILIKE '%food products%'")
```

but the result set is not organized. I want the results with complete "food products" string to be on top. but i am unable to arrange results some how.

Any help will be highly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try

> Products.where("name LIKE '%food%' OR name LIKE '%product%'").order("CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%food%' THEN 1
>   WHEN NAME LIKE '%product%' THEN 2 
>   ELSE 100 END)

This will give you result as per your sort order.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where you probably want to take advantage of full text search in Postgres. The [pg_search gem](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) makes this very easy to implement in rails.  Add `gem 'pg_search'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle`.

In your model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_name, :against => :name
end
```

Now you can use this method and it should put the "food products" result on top if that is the exact match:

```
Product.search_by_name('food products')
```